# Collectionview in TableView - How Perform segue? - Swift

Tags: swift, collectionview

I wanted to make an app like Netflix. There is collection in tableview. I was able to show all the cells properly in the viewcontroller.

But when I press the movies in the collection, I want to send the performsegue and movie model. Would you help me with this topic.
[image: Text]

```
extension HomeTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movieSection?.movies.count ?? 0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellcollection = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        cellcollection.imageMovie.image = UIImage(named: movieSection?.movies[indexPath.row].imageSmall ?? "")
        return cellcollection
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        
    }
  
}
```

```
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies?.response.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablecell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.movieSection = movies?.response[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 207
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Only a `UIViewController` can perform a segue. So you need a way for your collectionView to tell the tableView (which is on the UIViewController) to do so.

Comment: Possible way, use closure: on `HomeTableViewCell`: `var onDidTapOnMovie: ((Movie?) -> Void)?`, In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { onDidTapOnMovie?(movieSection?.movies[indexPath.row]) }` and then in `HomeViewController`, after `cell.movieSection = movies?.response[indexPath.row]`: `cell. onDidTapOnMovie = { [weak self] movie in performSegueAndKeepMovie }`?

Comment: You should try to look at  compositional layout for your needs. You only need 1 collection view.. see [this great example](https://youtu.be/SR7DtcT61tA)